# Clear stuck reminder in Outlook 2011 Mac?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

I've got a reminder that won't go away after dismissing.  The calendar event no longer exists.  Using Outlook 2011 with an Exchange account.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to your `tasks` and see if it's there, if so, delete it

Comment: not sure how to run this command from mac terminal, but shut down outlook and open it with `/cleanreminders` switch.

Comment: I was looking yesterday for how to do that on the mac side.  If someone puts up specifics I'll accept the answer just because it's not available elsewhere!

Comment: apparently mac office 2011 doesn't support command line switches. I'm still looking

Comment: Sorry, I can't find anything except [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2360509) which seems... excessive.

Answer (score 4):

The full solution seems to be:

1. open Outlook and turn off "calendar reminders" under the Outlook menu drop-down
2. reboot or log out and back in while holding the shift key to disable startup apps
3. open a terminal and navigate to the correct folder. On my system, it was:

   ```
   /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Outlook.app/Contents/MacOS
   ```

and then type

```
./Microsoft\ Outlook /cleanreminders &
```

The command line solution [was found here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/342742-mac-outlook-2011-reminder-keeps-popping-up).

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Wayne's answer, because that also helped me:

1. Go into Calendar view by clicking on the Calendar icon under the Mail icon on the lower left of the main Outlook window. This will bring Outlook to the calendar view.
2. From the account that has issues (or the only top level calendar label form the left view), right-click (or option-click) on the top most calendar item in the tree view.
3. Click on Folder Properties. A new window appears titled "Folder Properties: Calendar"
4. Under the General Tab click on the Empty button.

This will remove ALL calendar items from the local computer and the next time a sync is performed all items from the server will sync back and hopefully the repeating reminders will now be gone.

Comment: this did not clear my stuck reminder.